# How to disable logging selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, logging, console-application

When I create new chromedriver it always show logging below:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 61158
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61161/devtools/browser/ec79c8c1-9d0f-4a91-967d-d3f97e24ec20
```

How I can prevent this but not use:
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; because when you use it, it will help you close and clean chrome driver and chrome you was open.
I also tried:

```
    options.AddArguments("--disable-logging");
    options.AddArguments("--silent");
    options.AddArguments("--log-level=3");
```

But it not working, some thing like:  service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true; also only clear off 1 part

Comment: I've searched periodically for this, but I've never found a solution.

Comment: I wonder if you can use [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0)? Cleaning up the web driver might be the real issue. You shouldn't need a command prompt window to do that. Please [edit] your question to include the code to initialize and dispose of the web driver.